# AJAX cannot pass multiple data to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

In the following code, input 1, 2, 3 are bootstrap input fields and the file is 'processor.php' itself.

```
<script>
   $('#create1').click(function(e) {
      var ip1 = $('#input1').val();
      var ip2 = $('#input2').val();
      var ip3 = $('#input3').val();

      $.ajax({
          url  : 'processor.php',
          type : 'POST',
          data : {
            obj1 : ip1,
            obj2 : ip2,
            obj3 : ip3
          }
      });
   });
<script>
```

Later on, at the end of the file, I have the following PHP code

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['obj1']) {
  echo $_POST['obj1'];
  echo $_POST['obj2'];
  echo $_POST['obj3'];
}
?>
```

Howevery, it just show the content of only ip1 and get me the errors for obj2, obj3 like this: **Notice: Undefined index 'obj2' on: ...**

Can anyone give me the reason why this happens and how to fix that. I'm a newbie

Comment: try to alert your values in js code

Comment: Have you ever control values of ip1 and ip3?

Comment: also you are missing one closing bracket in `if(isset($_POST['obj1'])`..

Comment: you are only checking if isset for obj1 should check individually for all obj2, obj3

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments. I've check the value of ip2 and ip3 and make sure that they are not empty. Maybe it's my PHP if statement has problem. I'll check again

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this...

 <script>
  $('#create1').click(function(e) {
  var ip1 = $('#input1').val();
  var ip2 = $('#input2').val();
  var ip3 = $('#input3').val();
  var dataString = "obj1="+ip1+"&obj2="+ip2+"&obj3="+ip3; 
  $.ajax({
      url  : 'processor.php',
      type : 'POST',
      data : dataString
  });
 });
 <script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
        $obj1    = (isset($_POST['obj1'])    ? $_POST['obj1']    : '');
        $obj2   = (isset($_POST['obj2'])   ? $_POST['obj2']   : '');
        $obj3 = (isset($_POST['obj3']) ? $_POST['obj3'] : '');
       echo $obj1;
       echo $obj2;
       echo $obj3;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking if `$_POST['obj1']` is set. Not the others, so you may get failure notices if they're empty.

The error you're getting **Notice: Undefined index 'obj2' on: ...** it means the index of the array it's trying to access doesn't exist. In other words $_POST['obj2'] has no value assigned to it.

You need to check each variable individually before you try to work with it.

```
$object1 = ""; // Set a default value
if(isset($_POST['obj1']))
{
  $object1 = $_POST['obj1']; // Assign the $_POST value if one exists
}

// Now repeat for the rest
$object2 = ""; // Set a default value
if(isset($_POST['obj2']))
{
  $object2 = $_POST['obj2']; // Assign the $_POST value if one exists
}

$object3 = ""; // Set a default value
if(isset($_POST['obj3']))
{
  $object3 = $_POST['obj3']; // Assign the $_POST value if one exists
}

// Now $object1 will either have the default value, or the $_POST value if one exists
echo $object1;
echo $object2;
echo $object3;
```

**Note:** For the sake of debugging you can use `var_dump();` to see the contents of a variable on your page.

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

This is helpful to confirm a value/array/object contains what you expect it to.

Comment: Thank you for the idea of checking each obj. I haven't thought about that. Silly am I

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   $('#create1').click(function(e) {
      var ip1 = $('#input1').val();
      var ip2 = $('#input2').val();
      var ip3 = $('#input3').val();

      $.ajax({
          url  : 'processor.php',
          type : 'POST',
          data : {obj1="+ip1+"&obj2="+ip2+"&obj3="+ip3}
      });
   });
<script>
```

Or if this doesn't work
send data as one string and then seperate it in php

```
 data : {obj1="+ip1+"%%"+ip2+"%%"+ip3}
```

"%%" is separator

Hope This helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#create1parentcontainer').on("click","#create1",function(e) {
      var ip1 = $('#input1').val();
      var ip2 = $('#input2').val();
      var ip3 = $('#input3').val();

      $.ajax({
          url  : 'processor.php',
          type : 'POST',
          data : {
            "obj1" : ip1, //passing key set in ""
            "obj2" : ip2,
            "obj3" : ip3
          }
      });
   });
```

and in php set below code

```
<?php
        $obj1    = (isset($_POST['obj1'])    ? $_POST['obj1']    : '');
        $obj2   = (isset($_POST['obj2'])   ? $_POST['obj2']   : '');
        $obj3 = (isset($_POST['obj3']) ? $_POST['obj3'] : '');
       echo $obj1;
       echo $obj2;
       echo $obj3;
    ?>
```

**and see also in console what are you sending in ajax request for confirm may be something error shown in console**

Comment: Your solution seems to be correct. However, there are another problem is that when I load the page, because "#create1" has not been clicked yet, so all obj's will be ''

Comment: then use like on
first set parent container of create1 by this in this click action bind

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $('#create1').click(function(e) {
  var ip1 = $('#input1').val();
  var ip2 = $('#input2').val();
  var ip3 = $('#input3').val();

  $.ajax({
      url  : 'processor.php',
      type : 'GET',
          data : {
            'obj1' : ip1,
            'obj2' : ip2,
            'obj3' : ip3
          }
      });
   });
</script>

<?php
if (!empty($_GET['obj1']))
{
 echo $_GET['obj1'];
}
...
?>
```

Mind if you let us know which file shows the Notice error ?